# Function pointer call when signature is given only at runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

Consider the following situation:

You are given the pointer to a function as a raw pointer

```
void * function_pointer;
```

and the arguments to be passed to the function are available as a vector of a union type.

```
union Types {
  void   *ptr;
  float  *ptr_float;
  double *ptr_double;
  float  fl;
  int    in;
  double db;
  bool   bl;
};

std::vector<Types> arguments;
```

Thus, the functions' signature is only available in program state (as opposed to be known at compile time)

What would be the recommended way (C++ 11) to make this call ?

It would be possible to alter the arguments vector to something like this:

```
std::vector< std::pair<int,Types> > arguments;
```

where the first element of the pair would clearly identify of which type the argument is.

Technically, the signature is only given in the second form. Because only in the first form you can't tell what's the signature like.

Comment: Are you calling the functions with each element of the `vector` in turn or are you calling it with the whole `vector`?

Comment: I doubt this can be done in a portable way. They way it's usually done is with a piece of assembly that arranges the arguments (e.g. on the stack, or in the CPU registers) in a manner dictated by the platform's calling convention.

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language, the function's signature has to be known at compile-time. I can't see any workaround except passing the vector itself to the function and let it deal with it, as Cramer suggested. (Igor's suggestion is not C++ any more, even though he's right)

Comment: Why do yo want to take a function as a raw pointer? Any hints?

Comment: The function is returned by LLVM's JIT engine

Comment: So, it wasn't my choice. ;-)

Comment: @wpunkt I don't know the LLVM API, but I suspect it has a way to do generate the code you need. Perhaps building some IR by hand, generate a "closure" that takes no arguments and call this?

Comment: Hm.. This must be a common problem, perhaps you're right. Checking, ...

Comment: You cannot legally pass a pointer to function through a `void*`. Although in most platforms it will actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are existing libraries that can do what you describe, such as C/Invoke:

http://www.nongnu.org/cinvoke/

Answer (score 2):

In standard C, you must know the signature of a function (at compile time) in order to call it. Calling a function that is of one signature with a function pointer declared of the wrong signature will lead to undefined behavior.

There are libraries that use system-dependent assembly to construct function calls at runtime, like libffi.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just pass the union itself to the function and let it deal with what it wants? That way all the signatures are the same. If the argument isn't clear from context perhaps even pass two arguments, one saying what the union data is.

Finally if you MUST call a function which you cannot change the signature of I feel the only way is to use a `switch`, casting the pointer to the right signature before calling.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. It's not just 1 union. It's a vector of unions. Besides, changing the function is not really an option I would like.

Comment: If the argument is a vector of unions then the argument is known, the argument is a vector of unions.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a way to "bind" the pointer to an `std::function` object.. perhaps you might figure that out or someone else.. but this is as good as it gets I guess.. It might be do-able in assembly/inline-assembly though.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void Meh(int X, int Y)
{
    std::cout<<"Meh Arguments-> X: "<<X<<" Y: "<<Y<<"\n";
}

void Foo(std::string T)
{
    std::cout<<"Foo Arguments-> "<<T<<"\n";
}

void FuncAddr(int Args)
{
    std::cout<<"FuncAddr Arguments-> "<<Args<<"\n";
}

typedef void (*FuncPtr)(int);

int main()
{
    void* Ptr = (void*)&FuncAddr;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions;

    functions.push_back(std::bind(Meh, 1, 2));
    functions.push_back(std::bind(Foo, "Hey"));
    functions.push_back(std::bind((FuncPtr)Ptr, 200));  //Perhaps there is a way to "bind" the Pointer without the cast.. Not sure how though..

    for (auto it = functions.begin(); it != functions.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)();
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```